# How to calculate months in cck date field?

Tags: entities, 6, datetime

I have 2 cck fields 
1. date field with unlimited entries with to date option 
2. text field.

i am trying todo is when i enter **To** and **From** date automatically update text fied with total no. of years and month calculate.

**Like:**
to date : 14-Dec-2010
from date :14-Dec-2011

text field displayed 12 months 
**How may i do this?**

Comment: first off, if you have unlimited entries for your date field, that means a user could enter any number of dates, not just one, so do you need to iterate through all of these to get the number of months?

Comment: second, does this text field need to be displayed after entering the information when the node is being created and or edited, or just when the node is eventually displayed to the user?

Comment: So what you suggest using form alter function?